# htaccess display content in folder from root

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

[image]

- I have the following **folders structure** on my web server:
- I need some **rewrite rules**, let's say :

> When I visit [www.example.com/my/file1.php](http://www.example.com/my/file1.php) it will display content from [www.example.com/file1.php](http://www.example.com/file1.php)
>
> Similarly, [www.example.com/my/file2.php](http://www.example.com/my/file2.php) display content from [www.example.com/file2.php](http://www.example.com/file2.php) etc..

- My **.htaccess** file looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^my(\/?)$ /index.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^my/(.*)(\/?)$ /$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

- **The problem:**

> It redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (home page)

**Full htacess :**

[image]

[image]

Comment: please post .htaccess in textual form not an image.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your 2 rule, you may use this single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^my/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It not working. It still redirect to www.example.com (home page)

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question

Comment: can refer to the new one

Comment: Also can you tell me which URL is redirecting to home page? Did you try to test in a new browser?